# LogService fetch -> OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, google-app-engine

LogService fetch() results in error (see stack trace below):

Example code (Java 1.7, GAE 1.8.8):

```
...
logQuery.versions(Arrays.asList(new LogQuery.Version("default", "v3")));
logService.fetch(query);
...
```

The problem seems to be in ***versions()*** method! If I use deprecated method ***moduleVersions()*** no exception is thrown (even with much more results).

```
getVersions: [Version: moduleId=default versionId=v3]

com.google.appengine.api.log.LogServiceException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.google.appengine.api.log.LogServiceImpl.fetch(LogServiceImpl.java:38)
at com.google.appengine.api.log.LogQueryResult$1.computeNext(LogQueryResult.java:113)
at com.google.appengine.api.log.LogQueryResult$1.computeNext(LogQueryResult.java:98)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with logs is very memory consuming on App Engine. You can either use instance with more memory or use the appengine-mapreduce library.

See [Trying to get data from large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193899/trying-to-get-data-from-large-dataset/20198651#20198651)

Comment: I've upgraded from F1 to F2 already... but the problem seems to be in versions() method, because deprecated method moduleVersions works just fine even with 10x more log records.